# change directory and run the batch file in the same command prompt

Tags: java

Is there any way to open the command prompt and change directory in the command prompt and run the batch file in the same command prompt using java.

I know how to open the command prompt using java.
Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

You can encode the CD and the batch file in the value for cmd.exe /K.  From the doco (cmd /?):

> Note that multiple commands separated by the command separator '&&'
>   are accepted for string if surrounded by quotes.

For Example:

```
cmd /C "CD C:\ && Dir"
cmd /C "CD C:\Windows && Dir"
cmd /C "CD C:\Windows && MySuperSuperBatchFile"
```

For more detail, run:

```
cmd /?
```

from the command line.

Answer (score 7):

Be wary of Java's exec. It can hang if the batch process fills the output buffer, and cause other weird problems.

I suggest you look at apache [exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/). Specifically for your needs you should note that the Executor interface has a [setWorkingDirectory](http://commons.apache.org/exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/Executor.html#setWorkingDirectory(java.io.File)) method.

Basic usage:

```
Executor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
exec.setWorkingDirectory(new File("C:\\My\\Dir\\"));
CommandLine cl = new CommandLine("mybatch.bat");
int exitvalue = exec.execute(cl);
```

Comment: `exec.setWorkingDirectory()` takes a File as an argument not a String

Answer (score 2):

A couple of the [java.lang.Runtime.exec()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) variations does have a dir argument, so I assume you are not thinking of that?

You can compile the following C program and execute as a wrapper to start any program in any directory you want. If you use a String array with Runtime.exec you will avoid all issues of command line parsing/portability/proper quoting of the arguments.

I do not have any windows machine to test on here, but if you compile the C program to cdexe.exe you should be able to use it as the following:

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
                String[] s = { "c:\\some\\place\\cdexe.exe",
                "c:\\start\\dir", "c:\\my\\batch\\file.bat", "arg1", "..." };
                try {
                        java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
                } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

I guess unistd.h is maybe not available on windows, but just substitute with one containing a execv prototype.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>  // or hard code "int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        if (argc < 3) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Usage: %s <directory> <program> [arguments]\n", argv[0]);
                return 1;
        }
        if (chdir(argv[1]) < 0) {
                perror("Error");
                fprintf(stderr, "chdir(%s) failed\n", argv[1]);
                return 1;
        }
        argv[1] = argv[2];
        execv(argv[1], &argv[2]);      // use execvp if you want PATH to be searched
        perror("Error");
        fprintf(stderr, "execv returned\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that exec has a dir, -1 for C = 0... sorry

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to do from Java for goofy platform-independence reasons: basically what if you're running java on a system that doesn't have hierarchical directories?

There are a number of workarounds depending on what you're really trying to do, but possibly the simplest is to run the eventual command using 
`java.lang.Runtime.exec()`.

.

Answer (score 0):

get the environment var "comspec" then exec
%comspec% /c start/d directory /b batchfile.bat

Answer (score -1):

Keep the batch file in "path". You can execute it without going to any specific directory.

(For example you can have an entry "set path=%path%;C:..........\YourBatchFile.bat" in Autoexec.bat in Windows environment)