# JSP to run OS commands

Tags: jsp, shell

Can I use JSP to run OS commands ?

I have done similar thing in PHP and works fine using the shell_exec syntax.

Is it possible to do it in JSP ?

I was looking for something similar like this .

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime.exec(String s)
```

not sure what you want, essentially you are asking how to run os commands in java. [Refer to this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718124/run-cmd-line-in-java-fails)

And in JSP, there are more restrictions, due to security concerns , you might not able to access files located out of the sandbox(that is the web container).