# Change PWD of linux from JSP

Tags: java, linux, jsp, runtime.exec, absolute-path

I need to execute linux commands from JSP.
It is working fine.
But i need to start some sh file in a particular directory in linux through JSP. say /home/username/something/start.sh

```
try{
String command= "cd /home/username/something";

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./start.sh")


out.println("Child");
}
catch(Exception e)
{ out.println("Error");
}
```

It says FIle or Directory not found.

I tried `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pwd")`, It is showing something like "java.lang.UNIXProcess@fc9d2b" !! :O

I need to change the pwd and execute some commands through jsp. How can i do that??
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That `java.lang.UNIXProcess@fc9d2b` String you're getting is the `toString()` of the `Process` instance `exec()` is returning. In order to see the output of the command, you should [capture the standard output of the `Process`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/882772/851811).

Comment: Can you plz tell how to capture standard output of the `Process` ??

Comment: Use [`Process.getOutputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream()).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't (and actually, it seems you can't) set a working directory like that. Each `Process` object given by `Runtime.exec()` will have its own working directory.

As answered in [How to use “cd” command using java runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4884681/851811), you should be using the three argument version of `Runtime.exec()`, in which you provide a `File` that will be the working directory. From its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)):

> Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process with the specified environment **and working directory**.

Or even better, use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) along with [`ProcessBuilder.directory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)) instead:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("start.sh");
pb.directory(new File("/home/username/something"));
Process p = pb.start();
```