# How to run Hadoop command from JSP

Tags: java, linux, jsp, hadoop

TO run a hadoop program the command used is

```
hadoop/bin/hadoop jar hadoop/Anagram.jar com.hadoop.examples.anagrams.AnagramJob /user/hadoop-user/testdir /user/hadoop-user/outputdir
```

From PWD.

I need to run this command from a JSP page hosted in APACHE TOMCAT 7.0.
TO run linux command in JSP.

```
out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mkdir /tmp/testdirectory"));
```

Its working fine. But i need to run this hadoop command.

In reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361470/change-pwd-of-linux-from-jsp), I have done like this

```
  <%
try{

out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start-all.sh"));
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("hadoop jar hadoop/Anagram.jar com.hadoop.examples.anagrams.AnagramJob /user/hadoop-user/testdir /user/hadoop-user/outputdir5677");
pb.directory(new File("/home/hadoop-user/hadoop/bin/"));
Process p = pb.start();

}
catch(Exception e)
{ out.println("Error"+e);
}
%>
```

But it is throwing the exception

> java.lang.UNIXProcess@5a8a7e Errorjava.io.IOException: Cannot run
> program "hadoop jar hadoop/Anagram.jar
> com.hadoop.examples.anagrams.AnagramJob /user/hadoop-user/testdir
> /user/hadoop-user/outputdir5677" (in directory
> "/home/hadoop-user/hadoop/bin"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such
> file or directory

When i use like this
How can i resolve my problem. I need to run this command. but this problem is related to path. :(
Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: did you find any answer to this. If yes please share it I am also looking for something similar. Below is the question link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885780/running-hadoop-jar-command-from-java-using-runtime-exec/36887299#36887299

Answer (score 1):

Try: `./hadoop jar hadoop/Anagram.jar ...`

The PATH used is likely not containing the ".", or current directory.

This will make it search the bin directory that you're in.

Comment: java.lang.UNIXProcess@5b891 Errorjava.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./hadoop jar hadoop/Anagram.jar com.hadoop.examples.anagrams.AnagramJob /user/hadoop-user/testdir /user/hadoop-user/outputdir5677" (in directory "/home/hadoop-user/hadoop/bin"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory..... :(

Answer (score 0):

ProcessBuilder takes comma separated arguments, not the entire command like in post. Search for ProcessBuilder examples