# Running hadoop jar command from JAVA using Runtime.exec

Tags: java, hadoop, runtime, runtime.exec

I am trying to run an hadoop jar command from JAVA using Runtime.exec.
Below is the sample code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bin/hadoop", "jar /home/hadoop/jar/test.jar /user/hduser/myinput/input /user/hduser/newoutput"});
```

However I am not getting the desired output. Below is my hadoop command which I want to execute from JAVA:

```
bin/hadoop jar /home/hadoop/jar/test.jar /user/hduser/myinput/input /user/hduser/newoutput
```

I am not getting any exception as well. Is the way Runtime.getRuntime().exec is used is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your command with following command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar /home/hadoop/jar/test.jar /user/hduser/myinput/input /user/hduser/newoutput");
```

Comment: My file is in HADOOP_HOME is it still needed?

Comment: If your working directory is HADOOP_HOME and you are running within that, so its not needed

Comment: Are you sure it's the correct way to run this command because I don't see this working. It's also not throwing me an error or something.

Answer (score 1):

Give the class name where you defined the driver code.

```
bin/hadoop jar /home/hadoop/jar/test.jar Package_name.className /user/hduser/myinput/input /user/hduser/newoutput
```