# executing cmd command using a java program

Tags: java, cmd, command

i want to execute the following command using a java program.
"java -jar Demo.jar readExcelDemo.Hvd"

```
public class ExcelDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runTime.exec("cmd","/c", "cmd.exe","java -jar Demo readExcelDemo.Hvd");

            }
}
```

Comment: so what's the problem ?

Comment: The method exec(String, String[], File) in the type Runtime is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String)

Comment: so what is means is that there is no method that takes 4 string args

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runTime.exec("java -jar Demo.jar readExcelDemo.Hvd");
```

If above code is not okay, try this:

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runTime.exec("cmd.exe /c start java -jar Demo.jar readExcelDemo.Hvd");
```

If you want to watch cmd, you can use below code.
It will immediately close because of the /c flag.

```
 Process p = runTime.exec("cmd.exe /c start cmd /k java -jar Demo.jar readExcelDemo.Hvd");
```

Comment: If so, this is your command problem i think.Because code is fine.

Comment: i tried your edit code, it is opening the cmd prompt and immediately its closing. Unable to watch what its printing in console.

Comment: If you want to watch cmd, you should pause cmd.

Comment: "cmd.exe /c start cmd /k java -version"  could you please explain one by one in the command.

Comment: I deleted java -version to answer cosz this is my test command. /c i already explain and /k for pause the first cmd window.now okay?

Comment: i want to execute multiple commands like changing the directory and then executing the batch file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884681/how-to-use-cd-command-using-java-runtime this link will help you.

Answer (score 0):

create a .bat or .cmd file with content
java -jar Demo readExcelDemo.Hvd

change your code to

```
public class ExcelDriver {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = runTime.exec("cmd","/c", "myfile.cmd");

        }
```

}

Comment: The method exec(String, String[], File) in the type Runtime is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String)

Answer (score -1):

You can just call:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: i did not get any output.

Comment: but you get the output by just go to the cmd and type the command?

Comment: i want to execute through java program

Comment: Sorry, I just want to make sure that the command is working properly.

Comment: Anyway, my suggestion is the same to @Ye Win, and the command you raised on the question is wrong. The "Demo" should be "Demo.jar".