# Java Runtime Command to Change Directory & Compile LaTeX Source Not Working

Tags: java, terminal, pdflatex

I am currently working on a java project which automatically generates texts files with LaTeX source code. These files are written to the hard drive at a know directory. Instead of having to manually compile the LaTeX source into a pdf myself, I want to use `Runtime.getRunTime().exec()`.

I downloaded and installed BasicTeX. I do know that it is working properly. I can call the following in a new terminal window and the pdf is properly generated with no errors. Like this:

```
Kyles-MacBook-Pro:~ kylekrol$ cd Documents/folder/Report
Kyles-MacBook-Pro:Report kylekrol$ pdflatex latexDocument.txt
```

So I simply tried to use the following code before my program closed to compile the pdf:

```
private static void compileLatexMac(String path) {
    String s = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("cd " + path.substring(0, path.length() - 1) + " && pdflatex latexDocument.txt");

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd " + path.substring(0, path.length() - 1) + " && pdflatex latexDocument.txt");
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        System.out.println("outputs:");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        System.out.println("errors:");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

When I run this all I get back is the following without a pdf or a log file.

```
cd /Users/kylekrol/Documents/folder/Report && pdflatex latexDocument.txt
outputs:
errors:
```

I am not really sure what to make of this or why it isn't working - especially because I can call `cd /Users/kylekrol/Documents/folder/Report && pdflatex latexDocument.txt` from Terminal and it runs as desired.

If someone could point out what I'm missing here that'd be great. Thanks!

---

I ended up running into more issues using the three argument `exec()` command when running the jar file by double clicking on it. I fixed this by calling the following command which uses an extra `pdflatex` argument and only absolute paths.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pdflatex -output-directory=" + path.substring(0, path.length() - 1) + " " + path + "latexDocument.txt");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `&&` is expanded by the shell. `Runtime.exec` does not expand this operator and just attempts to executes the `cd` command with the remainder of the command line as arguments. Thus, your `pdflatex` command is never run.

If you want to run `pdflatex` with a particular working directory, use the [three-argument version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File)) of `Runtime.exec`.

Comment: So how would I edit the `&&` or what other operator should I use? I'm sorry I'm very familiar with this sort of stuff

Comment: @k.krol.27, Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4884715/391161).

Comment: I found that a couple minutes ago haha. Thanks I got it working now!