# How to push commit to git repository without adding Remote?

Tags: java, git, repository, bitbucket

I have some repository, like https://nickname@bitbucket.org/nickname/repo-name.git. I need to push some data to this repo, using Java.

So, basically I want to do these steps:

1. Create temporary directory (**tmp_path == /temp/tmp/dir**)
2. cd tmp_path
3. git init
4. git remote add origin https://nickname@bitbucket.org/nickname/repo-name.git
5. create temp file with needed data (**filanme == tmpfile.txt**)
6. git add filename
7. git commit --message="adding tmp file"
8. git push origin tmp-branch

But there is one problem. I [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884681/how-to-use-cd-command-using-java-runtime) make "**cd**" from Java. So I need another solution.

Is there any way to push some data to repository without local git folder?

Comment: Do you plan to start new processes to execute these commands? If so, yes, there is a way to start the process from a specific directory: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory-java.io.File-. But there are Java APIs to use git from Java, without starting processes. It's unclear what you actuallly want to do, since you didn't post any code.

Comment: @JBNizet my final target is to push List<String> of userData to some branch of specific git repo. Thank you for link, I will see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Java, so I can just give commands without `cd`.

```
git init /temp/tmp/dir
# create tmpfile.txt in /temp/tmp/dir
git --git-dir=/temp/tmp/dir/.git --work-tree=/temp/tmp/dir add tmpfile.txt
git --git-dir=/temp/tmp/dir/.git commit --message "adding tmp file"
# your question says without adding remote, so we skip "git remote add"
git --git-dir=/temp/tmp/dir/.git push https://nickname@bitbucket.org/nickname/repo-name.git HEAD:refs/heads/tmp-branch
```