# How to execute 'cd' command and then a linux command in java

Tags: java

I have directory /tmp
then I need to execute cd and go to that folder.
Then I need to execute ./executeScript

Comment: learn about ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec in java.

Comment: In your runtime, give the path directly where your scripts exists, instead of executing cd and then executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

**Preparation**

To start solving the problem, I created a directory `/home/vulpini99/tmp`. In this directory, I created the bash-script `test.sh`, which will open firefox for us:

```
firefox
```

Then I created a java-file named `LinuxCommand.java` in the directory `/home/vulpini99`.

**Main part**

`cd` is just an internal shell command and not an executable program, so I suggest to just use the full path of the bash-script. So the command we want to execute is

`bash /home/vulpini99/tmp/test.sh`.

In Java, you can use `Runtime` for this purpose:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class LinuxCommand {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            run.exec("bash /home/vulpini99/tmp/test.sh");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vulpini88... Much appreciated for your response, but I don't want to hardcode the path. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It becomes quite complicated, if you really want to change the path. Some ideas on that can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884681/how-to-use-cd-command-using-java-runtime/21120323.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks so much... Answer to your question, I want to construct the path instead of hardcoded, Actually, I want to deploy my application as tar format in various servers, so if I hardcode the path then it might give me FNFoundException...

Comment: @SoumyaRB If my answer helped you, I would appreciate if you upvote and/or accept it. You can do this by clicking on the checkmark and the triangle over the zero if you want.